# Fan spins but not booting. PSU or Motherboard Issue?

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, fan

I upgraded graphics cards (gtx1050 LP), ssd and memory on my (5+ years old) Lenovo h520s desktop. it worked for a couple days and suddenly not booting after a restart. Is it a PSU or motherboard issue?

Upon pushing the power button:

- fan spins
- external display shows no signal
- no beeps
- second hhd seems running
- caps lock not working (not lighting up when pressed)

So my questions are:

- I am thinking that PSU is failing as it's old, so i am thinking to get a new one
- I wonder if 240w is enough?
- Or is it a motherboard issue? I think i can get a new one too
- Or is it other issues?

This is the current specs:

- motherboard: lenovo CIH61M1 V1.1
- ssd: intel ssd d3-s4510
- hdd: sesgate 1TB
- graphics: msi gtx 1050 LP
- PSU: AcBel PC9053 (240w?)
- Ram: Team ddr3 1600 8GB x2

I switch back to the old config however the symptoms are the same.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: 1. When you say *fan spins*, I assume this is the *CPU cooling fan*? 2. When you say *second hhd seems running*, what do you mean exactly by that? 3. *caps lock not working (not lighting up when pressed)* yes that means your USB ports are not powered at that moment.

Comment: Please post full detailed specs of *all* hardware involved and I'll see if I can help you.

Comment: specs:
- motherboard: lenovo CIH61M1 V1.1
- ssd: intel ssd d3-s4510
- hdd: sesgate 1TB
- graphics: msi gtx 1050 LP
- PSU: AcBel PC9053 (240w?)
- Ram: Team ddr3 1600 8GB x2

Comment: 1. all fans - cpu, psu, graphics card, case

Comment: 2. i can hear the physical moving sound of the internal components (normal sound)

Comment: added specs to the question

Comment: ok I'll have a look :)

Comment: Have you tried booting *but* without the new GPU? Your G2030 CPU has a graphics processor so you should be able to try that. I would try all graphical ports (as possible with cables/screens you have).

Comment: From what I can find online, there does not seem to be any diag LEDs on this board, can you confirm that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130892/discussion-between-nicholas-and-avia).